# Visio 2010, how to change the text to horizontal on a line that is vertically aligned?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have a line that is pointing downwards.

I have added some text description to this line and I would like it to be horizontally aligned, but I can't find a way to change the orientation. By default the text faces the same direction as the line (arrow).

How can I get the text to be horizontally aligned?

Thanks

Comment: SO is a *programming*-related site. Questions about the usage of particular software belong at superuser.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use the Text Block Tool, which will let you rotate the text however you want.

In Visio 2010 the Text Block Tool is right on the main Home tab. It is to the right of the Text tool. The icon has the letter "A" with a arrow going around it. Keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>

In Visio 2007 the Text Block Tool is located in the Toolbar along with the Text Tool. Just click the down arrow on the Text Tool to select the Text Block Tool. Then rotate the text horizontal.

Answer (score 7):

Bearing in mind its Visio 2010 the OP asks about:

Double click the connector so that you can add your text. Click out of the text and it will be horizontal.

Now go to the **Home** Toolbar and look in the **Tools** section (Where you selected connector). Here, you will find the letter A surrounded by a swirl arrow.

Ensuring your connector is selected, this button will be active and not greyed out. Select the button and the rotation of the text becomes active.

Comment: This is by far the better answer as a Text Block will not follow the line